# Wifi Adpator Not Found

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, drivers, realtek

I just Dual booted my Asus TUF FX505dt with windows and ubuntu but I can't connect to internet via wifi.

My wifi card is realtek wifi adaptor

and output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:3041]
    Kernel modules: rtw_8821ce, rtl8821ce
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
```

can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Realtek RTL8821CE Driver by:

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

or from this [git repo](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce):

```
sudo apt install bc module-assistant build-essential dkms git
sudo m-a prepare
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce.git
cd rtl8821ce
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Unload the `rtw_8821ce` driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtw_8821ce
```

Reload `rtl8821ce`:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8821ce
sudo modprobe -v rtl8821ce
```

Then:

```
echo "blacklist rtw_8821ce" |sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: Brother i have done it and 
" Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
rtl8821ce-dkms is already the newest version (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
"  it shows this

Comment: @MR_LUCIF3R See my edit please.

Comment: '
insmod /lib/modules/5.8.0-55-generic/updates/dkms/rtl8821ce.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8821ce': Operation not permitted
"
this message is showing
 can you contact me ... via discord or soething a email?

Comment: @MR_LUCIF3R become root `su -` then execute `modprobe` command.

Comment: Hey Man thanks ,,,,, idk how it happened it just helped a lot

Comment: @MR_LUCIF3R `su -` then give your root password

Comment: yAH iT dID .... but you know what ... i tried to super root and it is showing authorization failure

Comment: @MR_LUCIF3R Try the last command in the answer then reboot.